# How can I update my android widget faster on reboot?

Tags: android, android-widget

When I restart my phone, it takes more than a minute for onUpdate to get called and update my widget.

Otherwise, onUpdate is called quickly, such as adding another widget instance to my homescreen.

Since I show a loading message before the widget is updated, this makes it look like the widget hangs when the phone is rebooted.  I could load from local storage, but it could make the user think the data has not been updated and some error has occurred.